# bootstrap modal not open using jquery in typescript class in angularjs2 (rc5)

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I am working on an `angular2(rc-5)` app using typescript. I just made a loader component which just have to open modal using jquery inside a typescript class function. But it is not able to found `$` and modal function?

`import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';`

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: 'loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['loader.component.css'] 
})
export class LoaderComponent {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() message = "finally inside child scope.";

  showLoader(){
      $("#loaderModal").modal('show'); // error on this line
  }

}
```

**Error Report:**
 Error:- Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.
 [image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a runtime or compile error?

If it's a compile error you need to install typings:

Install typings for jquery and bootstrap `typings install dt~jquery dt~bootstrap --global --save`

More about typings you can find here: https://github.com/typings/typings

If it's a runtime error you should import jquery and bootstrap into your typescript file. What ModuleLoader do you use?

Comment: its a compile time error, I install all these things (typings) as you mentioned, but still giving the same error.

Comment: Check the image I have added above.

Comment: document.getElementById('loaderModal').style.display = 'block';

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with including typings. How does your tsconfig.json look like? Did you try to use typescript compiler from commandline, without a build tools?
BTW: I would also suggest to use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/ or http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/ so you won't need jQuery anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare the nes meaning of $ whith :

> declare var $: JQueryStatic;